# Time limit or built-in flush of HashTable entries

Tags: data, data-types

Is there a standard data type which is a struct or a table or a dictionary which will always delete objects that are older than t minutes? for example if I want to make sessions expire after 60 minutes. I don't want to traverse the whole structure of course. I think we can do it with 2 generations. Every hour it makes the new generation and copies the first to the second

```
if self.server.current_hour_epoch != current_hour_epoch:
    self.server.current_hour_epoch = current_hour_epoch
    self.server.g1 = self.server.g0
    self.server.g0 = {}
```

then when we make lookups we look first in g0 and then in h1

```
# Generation 0 - we know all sessions in here are valid.
if sessionkey in self.server.g0:
    userid = self.server.g0.get(sessionkey)
elif sessionkey in self.server.g1:
    # Generation 1 - a session in here might be valid.
    userid = self.server.g1[sessionkey]
```

But I never saw a standard object with this capability, even though I think it is a general solution to a common problem.

Answer (score 2):

You create a priority queue based on age. And when time progresses so the oldest element needs to be removed, you remove it. Priority queues are often implemented with a min-heap data structure (O(1) peek, O(log n) insertion or removal).